# automate input with python in another python file

Tags: python, input, automation

I've got this little guessing-game

```
#Guessing-Game.py
import random
random.seed()
randomnumber = random.randint(1,10)

def guess(number):
    while number!=randomnumber:
        number = int(input("Guess: "))
        if number < randomnumber:
            print("to low")
        else:
            print("to high")
    else:
        print("correct, it's", number)
```

and I would like it to be solved by another python script. Something like

```
#Guessing-Script
import Guessing-Game

for n in range(1,11):
Guessing-Game.guess(n)
```

but obviuosly this dont work because it's asking for an input.

How to solve my problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could split your `guess` functionality in 2 parts: one that does the comparison, and another that reads user input, and from the other module call repeatedly the one that does the comparison, until the right number is passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decide whether you want the guess to come from input or from the passed argument. If you want both to be possible, make two functions:

```
# guessing_game.py
import random
random.seed()
randomnumber = random.randint(1,10)

def guess():
    number = int(input("Guess: "))
    while number!=randomnumber:
        number = int(input("Guess: "))
        if number < randomnumber:
            print("to low")
        else:
            print("to high")
    else:
        print("correct, it's", number)

def single_guess(number):
    if number == randomnumber:
        print("correct, it's", number)
    else:
        if number < randomnumber:
            print("to low")
        else:
            print("to high")
```

This way, you can call:

```
import guessing_game

for n in range(1,11):
    guessing_game.single_guess(n)

#to low
#to low
#to low
#to low
#correct, it's 5
#to high
#to high
#to high
#to high
#to high
```

Comment: wasn't what I was looking for. Thanks anyway :)